# change avplayer play rate and then save video as a movie file

Tags: ios, avplayer, avassetwriter, avmutablecomposition

I have a video which I play by using avplayer.
And then I have a feature where user can change rate of the movie to go faster or slower. Is there a way to say this fast or slowed down movie?

I have looked into avassetwriter but I can't find a way to pass in a rate prperty.